# Removing #id from the url (bootstrap)

Tags: html, url, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've just created the bootstrap navbar on my website and I have the trouble with my url... 
For example I have something like this:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" href="#about">
        About
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And my website url looks like this: "something.html#about"
I would like to remove the #about from the url. I read that I should remove? the href from this li item, and put the #about in data-target but it doesn't work for me. What is the easiest way to fix this? Thanks for any respond.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `data-target` instead of `href`. It will help you to get rid of `#about` from the browser URL.

So instead of

```
href="#about"
```

use

```
data-target="#about"
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are a beginner in HTML and how web pages work.

The href attribute of the HTML element a(nchor) defines the hyperlink. The "#something" points to an ID within a HTML web page. It is accessible by the JavaScript on the specific page.

In this case, your href points to the current page as no other page is referenced (the href has nothing like href="otherPage.html#about").

It might be needed by the bootstrap framework. There is nothing wrong with it. Embrace it, it is part of the internet and how browsers work.